# Dilemma while selecting a design pattern

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, design-patterns, factory

I am looking to select a design pattern for a project I am working on and was wondering if I can get some input.

---

**Background**

An interface called **Ranker** is defined as follows.

```
interface Ranker<T> {
    public void rank(List<T> item);
}
```

Each implementation of Ranker can have multiple Rankers as member variables and each of the member Rankers can have multiple Rankers as their member variables. You get the idea. A Ranker can use another Ranker to help rank it's items.

In my particular case I have 27 different Rankers defined each of which Rank a **different** dataType. 26 of those rankers will be used by one of the Rankers to be ultimately be able to rank the items.

```
RankerForTypeA
  RaknerForTypeB 
    RankerForTypeC
    RankerForTypeD
    RankerForTypeE
  RankerForTypeF
    RankerForTypeG
      RankerForTypeH
        RankerForTypeI 
      RankerForTypeJ
  RankerForTypeK
  ...
```

Meaning, **RankerTypeA** has, RankerTypeB, RankerTypeF and RankerTypeK as members and needs them in order to appropriately rank items of type **A**.

---

**Problem**

The instantiation logic for each of the **Rankers** is different. I would like to use some sort Module/Factory/etc that helps me create these rankers. I ultimately need it to create **RankerForTypeA**. I had something like this in mind.

```
 interface RankerFactory {
      Ranker<A> getRankerForA(paramsForA);
      Ranker<B> getRankerForB(paramsForB);
      Ranker<C> getRankerForC(paramsForC);
      ...
 }

 public class DefaultRankerFactory implements RankerFactory  {
      Ranker<A> getRankerForA(paramsForA) {
          getRankerForB(paramsForB)
          ...
      }
      Ranker<B> getRankerForB(paramsForB) {
          getRankerForC(paramsForC)
          ...
      }
      Ranker<C> getRankerForC(paramsForC) {
          ...
      }
 }
```

Here's the bit tricky part. I would like to make it easy for people to let's say use custom rankers where they see fit. Going back to the hierarchy I drew before, let's say for **TypeB**, people wanted to use **CustomRankerForTypeB** instead of **RankerForTypeB**, they should be easily be able to. So in that case the hierarchy would look like

```
RankerForTypeA
  CustomRankerForTypeB 
    ...
  RankerForTypeF
    RankerForTypeG
      RankerForTypeH
        RankerForTypeI 
      RankerForTypeJ
  RankerForTypeK
  ...
```

So here, if they want to create **RankerForTypeA**, they can't directly use **DefaultRankerFactory** because it uses **RankerForTypeB** instead of **CustomRankerForTypeB**. So normally you would be like, they can just create a new implementation of **RankerFactory** but then it would have a lot of duplicate code because the instantiation logic of a lot of the of other parts of **RankerForTypeA** is similar.

So, for this scenario I had something like this in mind.

```
 public class CustomRankerFactory extends DefaultRankerFactory  {

      Ranker<B> getRankerForB(paramsForB) {
          //Define instantiation logic for CustomRankerForTypeB
          ...
      }

 }
```

This solution however doesn't seem right to me because it relies heavily on inheritance. CustomRankerFactory **is not necessarily a** DefaultRankerFactory, so that approach doesn't seem right. Plus the approach here doesn't seem like a Factory pattern even though I keep going back to that term. I am looking for help with the best approach to define the "Factory" so that it's modular and easily extensible. Open to all forms of input.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is quite a well-thought-out question for a new user. There is a tour here: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid having custom `RankerFactory` implementations inherit from `DefaultRankerFactory`, you can create an abstract base class (ABC) from which both `CustomRankerFactory` and `DefaultRankerFactory` inherit, where the `DefaultRankerFactory` does not override any default behavior. For example:

```
interface RankerFactory {
    Ranker<A> getRankerForA(paramsForA);
    Ranker<B> getRankerForB(paramsForB);
    Ranker<C> getRankerForC(paramsForC);
    // ...
}

public abstract class AbstractRankerFactory {

    public Ranker<A> getRankerForA(paramsForA) {
        // ...default behavior...
    }

    public Ranker<B> getRankerForB(paramsForB) {
        // ...default behavior...
    }

    public Ranker<C> getRankerForC(paramsForC) {
        // ...default behavior...
    }
}

public class DefaultRankerFactory extends AbstractRankerFactory {}

public class CustomRankerFactory extends AbstractRankerFactory {

    @Override
    public Ranker<C> getRankerForC(paramsForC) {
        // ...custom behavior...
    }
}
```

This does not actually change the behavior you are currently exhibiting, but it removes the `DefaultRankerFactory` from the `CustomRankerFactory` hierarchy. Thus, the hierarchy now reads `CustomRankerFactory` is an `AbstractRankerFactory` rather than `CustomRankerFactory` is a `DefaultRankerFactory`.

---

Caution for this next example: This is not necessarily the "best" design approach, but it is a valid one and may suit your needs in a particular situation. In general, though, it is a good idea to create an ABC instead. Essentially, use the following technique sparingly.

In Java 8, there were additions to existing interfaces that would have broken existing functionality in both the Java libraries and in user-defined classes that implemented these interfaces. For example, the `Iterable<T>` interface added the following method:

```
public void forEach(Consumer<? super T> consumer);
```

This would have required that *all* implementations of the `Iterable<T>` interface, including in user-defined classes (not just in the standard Java library), be updated. The Java team decided that this was too large of a burden to place on developers (it would have essentially broken a majority of existing Java code), but they still wanted to add important features such as the functional `forEach` method, so they compromised and added the `default` keyword to Java.

This keyword allows an interface to provide a default implementation that is used by all implementing classes, unless the implementing class manually overrides the default implementation. For example, the JDK 10 implementation of `forEach` in `Iterable<T>` is:

```
default void forEach(Consumer<? super T> action) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(action);
    for (T t : this) {
        action.accept(t);
    }
}
```

In practice this meant that all `Iterable<T>` implementations had the `forEach` method added without having to rewrite any code. In the case of your ranker system, you can utilize this `default` keyword to remove the ABC and reduce the complexity of the factory hierarchy. For example:

```
interface RankerFactory {

    default Ranker<A> getRankerForA(paramsForA) {
        // ...default behavior...
    }

    default Ranker<B> getRankerForB(paramsForB) {
        // ...default behavior...
    }

    default Ranker<C> getRankerForC(paramsForC) {
        // ...default behavior...
    }

    // ...
}

public class DefaultRankerFactory implements RankerFactory {}

public class CustomRankerFactory implements RankerFactory {

    @Override
    public Ranker<C> getRankerForC(paramsForC) {
        // ...custom behavior...
    }
}
```

This does reduce the complexity of the hierarchy, but keep in mind that it uses the `default` keyword for a purpose it was not originally intended and this may cause confusion in client code. If this approach is used, it should be documented that all default behavior is contained in the interface and that custom `RankerFactory` implementations should only implement (i.e. override) those methods for which they want custom behavior, rather than implementing all methods as is the normal practice with implementing an interface.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I have also considered that approach but was wondering if there some other approach that follows a more solid design pattern.

Comment: @jadeblack12 This may be one of those situations where a design pattern does not perfectly fit. Patterns are a very important part of software development, but they are not always perfect fits for a problem. Altering a standard design pattern or combining more than one pattern may be the best approach. There may be a pattern that better fits this problem, but I personally have not been able to bring one to mind, at least not yet.

Comment: @jadeblack12: Philosophical discussion point: Do the existence of design patterns reveal deficiencies in the language + standard libraries?

Comment: @Joshua To some extent. Every language has it's deficiencies. The fact that it is good at solving one problem usually means it is poor at solving another. Patterns are more solutions to common solutions and a lot of times they reveal issues with OOP more than a specific language. On the flip side, they also describe how to use the advantages of OOP to effectively solve a problem.

Answer (score 1):

I tackled a similar problem not so long ago. The solution went something like this:

```
public class RankerFactory {
    public virtual Ranker<A> getRankerForA(paramsForA);
    public virtual Ranker<B> getRankerForB(paramsForB);
    public virtual Ranker<C> getRankerForC(paramsForC);
    //...
}
```

The guy making `CustomRankerForTypeB` could easily inherit from `RankerFactory` and override `getRankerForB` with a method returning `CustomRankerForTypeB`. All kinds of stuff took arguments of type `RankerFactory`. Hint: this would be a good place for dependency injection if you are otherwise in a good place to use it. You could also use poor man's dependency injection and do

```
public class RankerFactory {
    private static RankerFactory factory = new RankerFactory();
    public static RankerFactory get_RankerFactory() { return factory; }
    public static void set_RankerFactory(RankerFactory newFactory ){ factory = newFactory; }
    //...
```

If you want this really flexible, which might be a double edged sword here, could instead do

```
public class RankerFactory {
    // I can't quite do this as generics sorry for the duplication
    public class FactoryA { public virtual getRanker() { return new RankerA(); } }
    private FactoryA a;
    public FactoryA getFactoryForA() { return a; }
    public void setFactoryForA(FactoryA value) { a = value };
    // ...

    public Ranker<A> getRankerForA(paramsForA) { return a.getRanker(); }
    public Ranker<B> getRankerForB(paramsForB) { return b.getRanker(); }
    public Ranker<C> getRankerForC(paramsForC) { return c.getRanker(); }
    //...
}
```

This also stacks with passing factories around (in my experience you want per-module factories something like half the time).

Comment: I see, so you're saying just buck the RankerFactory Interface and go straight with the default implementation which can then be extended by whoever.

Comment: I am a bit new to DI. How would I go about using something like guice here?

Comment: @jadeblack12: I use reflection + poor man's DI personally so I'm not the right one to ask.